# 参考書に記載されていたNetwork Namespaceの一括削除コマンドにおいてawkコマンドを使ってNamespaceをprintしている理由について

Tags: linux

現在Network Namespaceについての勉強をしており、Namespaceの一括削除を行う下記コマンドを参考書で見つけました。

```
for ns in $(ip netns list|awk '{print $1}'); do sudo ip netns delete $ns;done
```

上記コマンドで$(ip netns list|awk '{print $1}')として、awkで出力されるNamespaceの1列目を出力する処理を挟んでいるのは何故なのでしょうか。
手元で確認したところ、下記コマンドのようにawkで出力する処理を挟まなくてもNamespaceの一括削除は実現できていたので、何故このようなawkコマンドを挟んでいるのかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
for ns in $(ip netns list); do sudo ip netns delete $ns;done
```

Answer (score 2):

`ip netns list` が nsname と一緒に nsid も表示することがあるからです。

```
% ip netns list
nsname1 (id: 1)
```